# Doing mathematical operations on operands of various sizes, only known at runtime

Tags: c#, math, types, stack

I'm writing a small virtual computer, complete with its own instruction set. The thing that's giving me problems is the arithmetical instructions (add, mul, div, and so forth) because I want them to be able to work on operands of various different sizes (8, 16, 32, and 64-bit signed and unsigned integers, and 32 and 64-bit floating points - essentially, every numeric C# primitive type). The type of the operands aren't known until runtime.

I'm not sure of any elegant way to do this in C#, though. The operands, which usually live on a special stack type I'm writing, will be returned by a Pop method, but, as far as I know, methods can only have one return type.

Likewise, in the methods that perform the arithmetical instructions, having different operand sizes means I'd need to write a pretty unruly switch block.

I've seen the `dynamic` keyword, but I've heard it was better suited for interop with IronRuby/IronPython.

Is there any way I can solve this elegantly, without resorting to switch blocks or boxing everything in `object`s?

Comment: Why using universal type, you can overload the methods for different data type, this way it is more optimised for the type.Also, compiler helps in tracking type incompatible errors.

Comment: Another option would be to create a generic method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Comment: @Sherlock: Yeah, generic methods seem like one of the more feasible options. Sadly, generic types don't support mathematical operators, but there is a utility library that adds that functionality.

Comment: @usercr: That'd be quite a few methods, about 36 for every instruction.

Comment: Consider automatically converting all integer types to 64 bit integers and all float types to 64 bit floats. Then do the math in 64 bits. Then convert back, if necessary to the smaller type. There, now you only have *four* cases to deal with: long + long, long + double, double + long and double + double.

Comment: @Celarix: Note that `dynamic` boxes everything to `object`. `dynamic` is just `object` with a fancy hat on.

Comment: That means there will be boxing, right? In that case, I guess I'll go with the casts to long/double.

Comment: If you are considering a dynamic solution then boxing is the least of your worries. Boxing allocates a tiny amount of heap memory. Dynamic **starts the compiler**.

Comment: Long/double it is. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for ?

```
public static T Add<T>(T a, T b) where T: struct
{
    dynamic first = a;
    dynamic second = b;
    return first + second;
}
```

You can create a generic method like this for each mathematical operator you need.

Comment: Ah, the dynamic keyword can be used this way? That I didn't know.

Comment: @Celarix: "dynamic" simply means "start the compiler again at runtime and generate fresh code as though the runtime types had been known at compile time".

Comment: Hmm. I take it dynamic operations aren't very good in tight loops, then.

Comment: @Celarix: The generated code is cached. The second time through the loop, provided that the operand types are the same, uses the cached code rather than generating it fresh.  This provides a considerable savings, as the analysis is not cheap. If you have questions about the performance of `dynamic` the best way to get answers is to **test it yourself**.

Comment: In that case, I'll think I'll go with this - after proper performance testing, of course. This solution seems to give the best performance and readibility.

Comment: I note that if you're going to do this, the genericity of the formal parameters buys you nothing. You might as well just say `public static T Add<T>(dynamic a, dynamic b) where T : struct { return a + b; }` Note also that by doing this you will get the C# rules for addition applied, and maybe those aren't the rules you want.

Comment: @EricLippert No, then the `T` could not be inferred in a call like `Add(x, y);`.

Comment: The above code unexpectedly fails at runtime when `T` is `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, or `ushort`. An explicit cast to `T` seems to be needed. The boxed `dynamic` will be `int` since that is the smallest type for which `+` is defined!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: OK, let's suppose that the type of `T` can be inferred to be `int` by the fact that both arguments are `int`. Why call the method? If at compile time you know that you have two ints in hand, just add them!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: That's what I was pointing out when I said that you get C#'s addition rules. short + short is int, and there is no implicit conversion from int to short, so if what you want is short + short = short, then you'll have to put an explicit (dynamic!) conversion  in. And if you want rules for addition that differ from C#'s rules for addition, don't expect the C# dynamic analyzer to know that.